# Enforce type of expression delegate at compile time

Tags: c#, linq-expressions

I want to make a method that takes a `MemberExpression` and does something with it. At the moment I can do

```
private string myfunction<T>(Expression<Func<T>> exp)
{
    if (exp.Body is MemberExpression member)
    {
        // do stuff
        return "a string";
    }
    throw new Exception("wrong expression type");
}
```

However, I'd like this method to have compile-time type safety. Is there any way to *require* that the delegate passed in is a `MemberExpression`? I was thinking something like

```
private string myfunction(LambdaExpression<MemberExpression> exp)
```

However this obviously doesn't work because `LambdaExpression` isn't a generic type

Any ideas on how to ensure this? Or do I just rely on the runtime exception?

Comment: you're not using the generic argument `T` anyway, so why not just provide the `MemberExpression` in the first place?

Comment: `private string myfunction(MemberExpression exp)`? =)

Comment: I'm going to assume that your example code here isn't representative of what you are trying to do and it's likely the function does something like returning the `T` here. If so, then you are probably best with the method you are showing here. I've had to do something similar in the past.

Comment: Assuming the intent is to keep the argument as an expression tree, the short answer is "no". Only `Expression<TDelegate>` offers expression tree magic and that cannot further constrain the shape of the expression. You can make it a little more specific by making it `MyFunction<T, TMember> MyFunction(Expression<Func<T, TMember>> memberExpression)`, which at least demands a function of the proper signature and uses a suggestive name, but cannot enforce that that function actually be a member access expression at compile time (e.g. `(object o) => 42` also satisfies it).

Comment: There is nothing magical about `Expression` and compile time type safety in this case: think about a method that requires a `Func` parameter to be a of a certain form (e.g. a member access expression) - C# won't allow you to constrain the parameter beyond the `Func` types.

Comment: `myfunction(MemberExpression exp)` just moves the creation of the `MemberExpression` to the calling site - I was still hoping to be able to call it like `myfunction(() => foo.Bar)`. I'm using `T` as a throwaway type variable bc the signature `Expression<Func<object>>` results in the `exp.Body` being a `ConvertExpression` and its just a useless unwrap. Thank you all who have let me know that this isn't possible using `Expression<TDelegate>` - that's unfortunate but about what I was expecting 

Comment: Unfortunately C# doesn't really have an equivalent to the C++ member pointer.